# How to change node-red page title

Tags: node-red

How can I change node-red page title?

I have seen an issue on node-red's github page about this. But I could not understand which file I need to make changes.

[Here is that issue on github.](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/610)

[Same thing on node-red web site configuration section.](https://nodered.org/docs/configuration)

Which file do need to change? Do I need to install a node for editing theme?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation you link to:

> When run as a standalone application, these properties are read from the settings.js file. The location of this file is determined in the order:
>
> - set using the --settings|-s command-line argument
> - in the user directory if it was specified by the --userDir|-u command-line argument
> - in the default user directory: $HOME/.node-red/settings.js
> - in the node-red install directory

When you run node-red it logs the path to the exact settings file it is using, for example:

```
5 Feb 14:59:12 - [info] Settings file  : /Users/nol/.node-red/settings.js
```

Within that file you'll see the default set of settings within a block that starts:

```
module.exports = {


}
```

You need to add the `editorTheme` property within that block - remember to keep it a valid javascript statement, so you'll need a comma (`,`) between this and the previous setting.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
    ... all your existing settings ...

    editorTheme: {
        page: {
            title: "My own Node-RED title"
        }
    }
}
```

Once you've edited the file, restart Node-RED to pickup the changes.