# Customize NodeRed Web UI

Tags: node-red

Is there any way to customize Node-red UI(Web Portal)?
I have tried to get node-red git repo and unable to find it out.

Comment: Do you mean the Node-RED editor, or one of the various sets of nodes that provide a dashboard web page?

Comment: Yeah, Trying to customize Node-RED editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some limited customisations you can make to the appearance of the Node-RED editor, detailed here: https://github.com/node-red/node-red/wiki/Design:-Editor-Themes

See also this answer that explains a bit more on how to use it: [How to change node-red page title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625494/how-to-change-node-red-page-title/48625693#48625693)